# Matching Regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

I wanted to match a certain pattern to a few strings with a one regex line (if possible):

```
blah blah (1023 mega lbs) blah blah 1245 tons
blah 1023 kilo tons blah blah 1034 metric tons
blah 1023 feet 345 blah
$100 is a lot of money
```

I want to match numbers (first occurance in the line, for example) 1023 and its units (lbs, tons and feet) that may follow it after another word and store this as another string. However, I have to be careful of $100, because it's not a unit of measurement that I am concerned with and also any numbers that may follow the first sequence in that line.

My current approach has many nested `if statements` for example for the first line I have (not working): `\d*\s(.*)\s\w+` Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
with open("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        mo=re.match(r'[^\d]*(\d+).*?(tons|feet|lbs)', line)
        if mo: print mo.group(1), mo.group(2)
```

**Output**

```
1023 lbs
1023 tons
1023 feet
```

Also, if you have a line like `$100 money is too much for 100 lbs`, you can use this:

```
import re
with open("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        mo=re.match(r'.*?(?<![$\d])(\d+).*?(tons|feet|lbs)', line)
        if mo: print mo.group(1), mo.group(2)
```

And to match kilo, mega stuff:

```
import re
with open("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        mo=re.match(r'.*?(\d+).*?(mega|kilo|metric|) (tons|feet|lbs)', line)
        if mo: print mo.group(1), mo.group(2), mo.group(3)
```

**Output**

```
1023 mega lbs
1023 kilo tons
1023  feet
100  lbs
```

It is possible to store these units and modifiers in lists and join them with `|` to create a regex on the fly.

An example that matches all possible unit modifiers:

```
import re
with open("input") as f:
    for line in f:
        mo=re.match(r'[^\d]*(\d+).*?(\S*)\s*(tons|feet|lbs)', line)
        if mo: print "'{}' '{}' '{}'".format(mo.group(1), mo.group(2), 
                       mo.group(3))
```

**Output**

```
'1023' 'mega' 'lbs'
'1023' 'kilo' 'tons'
'1023' '' 'feet'
```

Comment: I also want to capture units in between the number and the actual unit, for example `1023 kilo tons`

Comment: Answer works well, but kind of complicated for me. If I didn't know the `middle` terms were gonna be `(mega|kilo|metric)`, could I do `(.*)` instead?

Comment: I tried it with `(.*)` and it worked (however, I get an extra space before the middle word. But when I tried it with `\w+` it didn't work

Comment: If I have `$.00025 per pound (=$10 per contract)` I want to obtain the values inside the paranthesis, but sometimes there are characters, which start the pattern, is there a way to omit them `=` in this case. So all I want is `$10 per contract`

Comment: And if I didn't know it was going to be an `=`, I would do `[*]?...`

Comment: I'm getting an error when I try to do: `[=]?\([^)]*\)`. I'm only trying to capture values inside the `()`

Comment: Try this: `r'.*?\([^$]*(\$[^)]*)\)'`

Comment: Yeah, that worked well, thank you. Do you know what's wrong with this: `r'\((\w+)\)'`, shouldn't this capture all the values inside the `()`?

Comment: `\w` only matches word characters, it won't match whitespace for example

Comment: Could you briefly explain your expression?

Comment: `.*?`: non greedy match, meaning give me the first match for whatever is coming next. `\([^$]*`: match a `(` and any number of non-dollar-sign characters. `(\$[^)]*)`: capture a dollar sign and anything upto the first `)`. `\)`: match a `)`.

Comment: Suppose, "per contract" in `(... per contract)` will persist, how would you match this?

Comment: `r'.*?\([^$]*(\$[^)]*? per contract)\)'`

Comment: I was able to do it without the `?` right before `per contract`, is there a problem with this approach?

Comment: Can you think of a way to remove the contents including the paranthesis to get `$.00025 per pound` with `re.sub`. I was able to do it using strings: `strs = line.strip.split('(')`

Comment: `re.sub(r'\s*\([^)]*\)', '', str1)`

Comment: Can you tell me if my understanding of the regex is correct: `r'[^\d]*(\d+).*?(\S*)\s*(lbs|feet)` #[^\d]* = match any character other than numbers (n times), #(\d+).*? = match a group of numbers (atleast once) - and any space after it, #(\S*) = match any non-white space char, #\s*(lbs|feet) = match any white space (0 or more occr.) and units following it.

Answer (score 0):

You might like using a regex tester such as http://regexpal.com/ or http://rubular.com/.

You have a problem because the `(.*)` in the middle is going to match greedily and end up capturing more than you intended. See [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5Cd%2a%5Cs%28.%2a%29%5Cs%5Cw%2b&input=blah%20blah%20%281023%20mega%20lbs%29%20blah%20blah%201245%20tons%0Ablah%201023%20kilo%20tons%20blah%20blah%201034%20metric%20tons%0Ablah%201023%20feet%20345%20blah%0A%24100%20is%20a%20lot%20of%20money).

Note that my solution should match all instances of `<number> <scale> <unit>` not just the first occurrence per line. I'm leaving it here for posterity.

```
(?:[^0-9$]|^)(\d+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)
```

Here it is in action, [link](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5B%5E0-9%24%5D%7C%5E%29%28%5Cd%2b%29%5Cs%28%5Cw%2b%29%5Cs%28%5Cw%2b%29&input=100%20kilo%20tons%20blah%20blah%20%281023%20mega%20lbs%29%20blah%20blah%201245%20tons%0Ablah%201023%20kilo%20tons%20blah%20blah%201034%20metric%20tons%0Ablah%201023%20feet%20345%20blah%0A%24100%20is%20a%20lot%20of%20money).

`(?:[^0-9$]|^)` says the match either starts at the beginning of the line or there's something that isn't a digit or a dollar sign before it (`?:` means we don't want to capture it). Then match the number `\d+` followed by two words `\w+`. You could replace the `\w+`s with more descriptive matches as in perreal's answer.